# Django Rest Framework как отформатировать ответ

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework

Когда сериализурую с помощью родного сериализатора

```
class NewsListSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Сериализатор Список новостей"""

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'body_text_preview','image', 'created_at')
    ...
```

Получаю такой json

```
{
   
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/news/?limit=100&offset=100",    
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 215,
            "title": "диллерское соглашение!",
            "created_at": [
                {
                    "year": "2020",                
                }
            ]
        },
       ....
       

 }
```

А когда всталяю свой json из словаря:

```
class CategoryListAPI(APIView):

    def get (self, request):
        root_nodes = cache_tree_children(ProductCategory.objects.all())
        dicts = []
        for n in root_nodes:
            dicts.append(recursive_node_to_dict(n))
        return Response(dicts)
```

То, получаю такого формата json

```
[
    {
        "id": 456,
        "name": "Автоаксессуары",      
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 3111,
                "name": "Жилеты светоотражающие",          
            }
           
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

В первом главный блок [] во втором {}
Как привести к единому стилю? и на сколько критична разница?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего поле `created_at` имеет связь "Один ко многим".

Но чтобы более точно ответить желательно посмотреть модель `News`, а также связанные с ней модели.

Разница  между [] и {} не критична.